# Turning on HP ProLiant DL 580 G5 with broken power button?

Tags: hp, hp-proliant

I have an HP ProLiant DL580 G5 whose power button does not work. The server runs, but the button does nothing.

Unfortunately, the server has turned off, and I guess my "boot on power" settings did not stay. I also know nothing about ILO, but maybe it's an option?

How do I turn on this server without a working power button?

Answer (score 2):

In the future, know that the power button is simply a momentary contact switch.  This means there are two wires and jumping them together for a split second with anything will energize (or deenergize, if held for a few seconds) the host.

Answer (score -1):

We found that the connector from the front panel was disconnected from the motherboard. Reconnecting fixed the issue.

Comment: How did u find that connector? Can u send some picture pls? I bought that dl today for whooping 300$ and once it turned, make noise when power cables connected, but power button stays black all time :(