# How to boot HP Proliant DL360 G6 with the front panel missing (no button)?

Tags: hardware, hp-proliant, boot

I came into possession of an HP Proliant DL360 G6 that I'm looking to turn into a file server.

Unfortunately the whole power button assembly is missing (complete with front panel, power button cable, as well -of course- the button itself). That part:

[image]

Apparently it was pried long ago as a means to repair another DL360 G6

I understand that booting a board is as simple as shorting the appropriate pins. But no matter how much I've searched, apparently, HP offers no pinout map of the power button connector of their boards. I can find no replacement in logical prices either.

Here's the front IO panel connector:

[image]

Now I *know* two of those pins when shorted will boot the board. But I'm afraid of shorting the wrong ones lest I do any lasting damage. Lacking any pinout map do you have any idea of how I should go about booting my server / trying things safely?

After having it booted for the first time I'll set it up booting remotely so this issue will go away. It's just for this -first- time.

Also I found this thread dealing with a similar issue: [Turning on HP ProLiant DL 580 G5 with broken power button?](https://serverfault.com/questions/770912)
But it had no satisfying answer, that is why I'm reposing the question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend just getting the right part or using another chassis. These servers are only worth a small amount.

[image]

It's HP part #493800-001 and is available with or without ribbon cable for [a small amount of money](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_odkw=dl360%20g6%20panel&_osacat=0&_from=R40&_trksid=m570.l1313&_nkw=493800-001&_sacat=0).

Comment: Thanks, didn't think to search ebay. That's very useful to know indeed.On an irrelevant note its PSU is dying as well and found (on the same ebay store) a DL360 G5 PSU (700w) for dirt cheap as well. Do you think it will be pin compatible with DL360 G6 board?

Comment: You need to use the G6/G7 PSU.

Comment: I actually have same model/gen server in my home lab.  Chugs away with no issues.  If you find the G6 PSU, and if you can afford two, you might consider getting both.  Single PS, single point of failure.  If you have more than one server, might even be worth it to ensure they all have two, and to put an extra one in the bench stock.

Answer (score 1):

You also might try sending wake-on-lan signal to the network card.  This will only work if wake-on-lan is enabled in BIOS.  It may be disabled for security reasons in some environments.

Research iLO to determine if there's a way to power the system on through iLO.  This will only work if iLO was active on the system before, and if you can get the credentials.  The default credentials are on the system tag thing you can pull out, if it's not removed.

Consider searching online for replacement front panel.  This should work unless the connections were damaged.

If an HP service tech is visiting, ask them where to look for info, or any tricks they might know to start the system.